# how to check if a datasource is in Edit mode or Insert Mode from a different Form

Tags: pascal, delphi-xe6

This code works great from its formBoxes:

```
if (dsContent.State in [dsEdit,dsInsert]) then
qryContent.Post;
```

But when checking from another form it does not like it on the dsEdit and dsInsert part: throwing undeclared identifier: 'dsEdit'. I already included the form on uses to use that form.

```
procedure TFormContents.btnSaveClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
   if (FormBoxes.dsContent.State in [dsEdit,dsInsert]) then
   FormBoxes.qryContent.Post;
 end;
```

Any help will greatly appreciated.

Comment: Add `db` to the uses clause of the second form.

Comment: @DavidA: actually `Data.DB` (you can drop the `Data.` prefix if `Data` is specified in the **Unit scope names** field in the Project Options), and you need to use `TDataSetState.dsEdit` and `TDataSetState.dsInsert` because XE6 uses **scoped enums**.

Comment: Oh yes, true. I'm still stuck with Delphi 5 at work.

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe I could not find this some where else. So simple, I think. Anyways Thank you guys. Now is working.